# Please see this issue on adding information to database

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I am using VB 2010 and have successfully connected it to SQL Management Studio 2008. I am able to make a connection to the database which i have called "TestDatabase" and can successfully add data to a database table. So now the problem lies in that I can only change the data I want to input into the database through code.  I want to use the textbox I have created for this purpose. Here's my CommendText:

```
sqCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TestTable" & "(FirstColumn, SecondColumn)" & "VALUES (textbox1,textbox1)"
```

The part in the string that I specified as (textbox1,textbox1) is for the values I want to put in but it seems that the word 'textbox1' is going in instead of the textbox's value.

I think there is some special syntax for this. Please be kind enough to inform me.

Comment: You'll need to do something to retrieve the value out of the textbox; I've never done VB, don't know. But I _do_ know that this looks like the start of an [SQL injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Injection). Switch to using [parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) in your applications. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are using it as a string.
You can try adding the textbox value inline:

```
sqCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TestTable" & "(FirstColumn, SecondColumn)" & "VALUES (" & textbox1 & "," & textbox1 & ")"
```

or even better take a look at [sql parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) which is a better way of dealing with `parameterized queries` since besides query simplicity, it prevents [sql injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

With sql parameters your statement could be:

```
sqCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TestTable" & "(FirstColumn, SecondColumn)" & "VALUES (@textboxValue,@textboxValue)"
sqCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@textboxValue", textbox1))
```

### Update:

The error you get is because you parse the textbox as an object straight to the database and not it's actual value. In my above example i just assumed textbox1 was a string variable declared before. To fix this you could alter your commands as such:

```
Dim myTextBoxValue As String
myTextBoxValue = textbox1.Text
sqCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TestTable" & "(FirstColumn, SecondColumn)" & "VALUES (@textboxValue,@textboxValue)"
sqCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@textboxValue", myTextBoxValue ))
```

Comment: Its giving me this error: No mapping exists from object type System.Windows.Forms.TextBox to a known managed provider native type.

Comment: I solved that but it is now saying: Incorrect syntax near '@textbox1'.

Comment: @Armaan Check my update but just a pointer for you, if you are just starting out with VB and .Net, you should really try to get a bit of theory into practise first or you will eventually spend more time here on SO trying to find answers from others to your problems without actually understand what you are doing since others will be doing the job for you

Comment: Thanks I practically do understand basics and I already did what you edited thanks anyway

Comment: You are welcome. Please dont take my comment the wrong way, just try to better undestand how things work around the language since it will be beneficial to you in the long term. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to concatenate the strings like this:

```
sqCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TestTable (FirstColumn, SecondColumn) VALUES (" & textbox1 .Text & ", " & textbox2.Text & ")"
```

However, your approach is not good at all. This kind of query execution is open for [SQL Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953.aspx) attack. You should consider using stored procedure or parameterized query.

Comment: Note that your improvement is _also_ vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. It's best to not perpetuate concatenated SQL strings, otherwise we'll never rid the world of that disaster.

Comment: I know, I edited my code and provided a link to MSDN's article about SQL Injection.

Comment: Oh wait I am getting error that "Operator & is not defined for types 'String' and 'System.Windows.Forms.Textbox'....what to do?

Comment: Significantly better, thanks. Though that article is hilarious in other ways, the bit about `AUX` and `COM` in file names is simply priceless. Yeah, it's easier to ask every programmer to filter those out than fix the filesystem....

Comment: You are supposed to use it as textbox1.Text.